# How to conduct performance testing where The service uses meteor js

Tags: performance, meteor, load, performance-testing, load-testing

How to conduct performance testing of my web service? The service displays a page, then the login form in the user's Personal account. It is necessary to enter and display the user's personal account. The service uses meteorjs. To display the personal account is necessary to emulate a browser. jmeter as I understand it is not suitable for this test. He(jmeter) is not able to emulate the browser can't request the js script on the client. Can you recommend tools for such testing? And how conduct ?
Thks

Answer (score 0):

Well-behaved JMeter test can do whatever browser does (from protocol-level perspective). [JMeter will not execute client-side JavaScript, neither it will render the response](http://jmeter.apache.org/), however if JavaScript generates a HTTP request - JMeter can even record it using [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) (or you can manually create this request by adding relevant [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler)

So the options are:

1. If your request is ad-hoc (i.e. periodic or on-demand) you can use HTTP Request sampler to mimic it
2. If your request is asynchronous ([AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp)) you can go for one of the techniques described in the [How to Load Test AJAX/XHR Enabled Sites With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-ajaxxhr-enabled-sites-jmeter) article or use [Parallel Controller](https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md#parallel-controller) plugin
3. And finally you can use JMeter for kicking off real browser instances using either [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverTutorial/) or [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)